# Can you pass a Grunt variable to a JavaScript function within a Grunt task?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

Here is an example of what I'm looking for:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({

    config: grunt.file.readYAML('_config.yml'),
    // example variable: <%= config.scripts %>

    copy: {
      scripts: (function() {
        if (config.scripts === true) { // I want to target <%= config.scripts %>
          return {
            expand: true,
            cwd: '<%= input %>/_assets/js/',
            src: '**/*.js',
            dest: '<%= output %>/assets/js/'
          };
        } else {
          return {
            // do nothing
          };
        }
      })()
    }

  });
};
```

I know Grunt can read the data from within a file using 'grunt.file.readJSON', and then have that data available with the following type of variable, '<%= pkg.value %>'.

What I'm wanting to do is to create a task with if/else options based on the variables from within the JSON file. What I'm unclear on is how to pass a Grunt variable '<%= pkg.value %>' into the JavaScript if statement in a way that it understands. I've tried passing it in the same Grunt format with '<%= %>', as well as stripping that part away and passing 'pkg.value', but neither seems to work.

If someone can shed some light on whether or not this can be done and how, I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide a concrete example of your grunt task please? (replace comments `do something` with your task)

Comment: See the edited example above.

Comment: Thank you. I post an answer. Try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I have more time, I'll probably look into some additional ideas, but based on the ideas offered here, this is what I ended up going with for now.

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  var config = grunt.file.readYAML('_config.yml');

  grunt.initConfig({

    copy: {
      scripts: (function() {
        if (config.scripts) {
          return {
            expand: true,
            cwd: 'input/_assets/js/',
            src: '**/*.js',
            dest: 'output/assets/js/'
          };
        } else {
          return {
            // do nothing
          };
        }
      })()
    }

  });
};
```

Thanks, everyone, for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of directly assign the grunt config in `config` attribute, store it in a variable (`gruntConfig`). Now you will be able to access it in the following code.

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    // store your grunt config
    var gruntConfig = grunt.file.readYAML('_config.yml');
    // init `script` with an empty object
    var script = {};
    if (gruntConfig.script) {
        script = {
            expand: true,
            cwd: '<%= input %>/_assets/js/',
            src: '**/*.js',
            dest: '<%= output %>/assets/js/'
        };
    }
    // Init Grunt configuration
    grunt.initConfig({
        config: gruntConfig,
        copy: {
            scripts: script
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Grunt has an API to read files, which you can use something like this:

test.json

```
{
  "fruit": "apple"
}
```

Gruntfile.js

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  grunt.initConfig({
    ...
  })

  grunt.registerTask('sample-task', function() {
    var test = grunt.file.readJSON('./test.json');

    if (test.fruit === 'apple') {
      // do this one thing
    } else {
      // do something else
    }

  });

  grunt.registerTask('default', ['sample-task']);
};
```

Comment: Can you share how I could use this to say, if a variable in the "test.json" file is set to true, run  taskA, or if it's false, run taskB? I've also updated my example in the original question for reference. Thanks!

Comment: there ya go! You just get a JSON object, so you can treat it as a regular JS object